# removing special element from an arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi
I have written this part of code .before the for loop I have this arraylist :

`[X :49.0  Y: 113.0 , angle :0.0, X :141.0  Y: 106.0 , angle :0.0, X :110.0  Y: 185.0 , angle: 1.0768211289482128, X :99.0  Y: 139.0 , angle: 1.9961041242180873, X :103.0  Y: 126.0 , angle : 2.4208694638343324]`
which show `"x" and "y" and "angle"` of some points.
but in the for loop I want to remove those elements that are more than

`X :110.0  Y: 185.0 , angle: 1.0768211289482128`

BUT it print this array for me :

`[X :49.0  Y: 113.0angle0.0, X :141.0  Y: 106.0 , angle:0.0, X :110.0  Y: 185.0 , angle: 1.0768211289482128, X :103.0  Y: 126.0 , angle: 2.4208694638343324]`
which is incorrect

```
 int size  = list .size();
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        if (list.get(i).getAngle() > pivot.getAngle() ) {
            list.remove(i);
            size--;

        }
    }
```

please help me 
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you remove an element it shifts the indices of the following elements down by 1. The simplest fix is to go in reverse:

```
for (int i  = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (list.get(i).getAngle() > pivot.getAngle() ) {
        list.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice to see we both had the exact same approach :)

Comment: @Jon: Yes. I see we also both reflexively used Google style when formatting the "for" line... :-)

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you to get an [`Iterator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) from the `list` and use [`iter.hasNext()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), [`iter.next()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) and [`iter.remove()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), like this:

```
 Iterator<Point> iter = list.iterator();
 while (iter.hasNext())
     if (iter.next().getAngle() > pivot.getAngle())
         iter.remove();
```

---

Another option would be to put them in a `SortedMap`, let the angles represent the keys, and use `tailMap(pivot.getAngle())` to get those points with a larger angle than the pivot.

Comment: This answer is much nicer than the others (+1)

Answer (score 4):

When you remove the element, you should also lower your index value (`i`) as otherwise it will skip the next value - because the values will have shifted. For example, imagine you originally had values `{ a, b, c, d, e }`. On the iteration where `i==2`, you'd look at `c`. If you then remove `c` you're left with `{ a, b, d, e }`... when `i` is incremented to 3 in the iteration part of the `for` statement, that means `list.get(i)` would return `e` - so you'd never look at `d`.

You *can* fix this by adding an `i--;` statement inside your `if` block... but a simpler approach is to work backwards from the end:

```
for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (list.get(i).getAngle() > pivot.getAngle()) {
        list.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you might want to consider creating a new list which only contains the elements you *do* want to keep:

```
List<Foo> validValues = new ArrayList<Foo>();
for (Foo foo : list) {
    if (foo.getAngle() <= pivot.getAngle()) {
        validValues.add(foo);
    }
}
```